# which code is better based on performance in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have some data of transactions,

first of all I created with my basic knowledge using for loop and than I am advised to use with some advance code..

here I want to know that does it matter speed or performance, whats thee problem if I use basic method

here is my code

```
double get count expense{
    double total = transactionlist.fold(0, (previous, current) => previous + current.amount);
    return total;

}
```

I was using this following

```
 double total=0;

    for(int x=0;x<transactionlist.length;x++)
      {
        total=total+transactionlist[x].amount;
      }

return total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are pretty much the same regarding to performance. Actually the second one is how the first one works under the hood.

The first one gives you more readability. That's why you should aim for the first solution.